# Extract Text after special character in a multi line Excel Cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have multi line data in a cell (G3) that looks like

X: 1
Yen : Noodles
Amazon: 21cm

I want to extract all the data after the ":" symbol into cell F3.
I have tries Split to text and then MID and CONCATENATE but not working because data in G3 should remain same.
The values after ":" keep changing
The return desired is 1 Noodles 21cm

Comment: please show the exact return desired.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for pointing out, updated!

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: @ScottCraner 2016

Comment: are the values before the ":" always the same (meaning "X", "Yen", "Amazon")?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, the values after ":" keep changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the User Defined Fuction:

```
Public Function Klean(s As String) As String
    Klean = ""
    arr = Split(s, Chr(10))
    
    For Each a In arr
        Klean = Klean & Mid(a, InStr(a, ":") + 1) & " "
     Next a
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With 2016:

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","</b><b>"),CHAR(10),"</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[2]")&" "&
 FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","</b><b>"),CHAR(10),"</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[4]")&" "&
 FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","</b><b>"),CHAR(10),"</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[6]")
```

With Office 365 or 2019 we can use TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","</b><b>"),CHAR(10),"</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&{2,4,6}&"]"))
```

[image]

Comment: Suggestion: Maybe a more general solution could be `=TRIM(LET(X,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),TEXTJOIN(" ",,REPLACE(X,1,FIND(":",X),""))))` or use something to return all even nodes through xpath.

Comment: @JvdV Suggestion: Put that as an answer and get some points.  I see that as something a future reader might want if they have a different number of items.